# Cannot run a very clean Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm very new to Java Technology (Normally working on NodeJs and PHP but got a requirement to work with Spring Boot). I just want to run 'Hello World' on Spring MVC. But I've already spent a day. I don't know why it's super hard to just initialise a project.

I built a project from https://start.spring.io/

```
Project: Marven, LanguageL Java, Spring Boot:2.2.6, Packing: Java, Java: 11
Dependencies: Spring Web WEB, Thymeleaf and Spring Boot DevTools.
```

My mvn -version,

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_TH, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

My pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>front-end-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>front-end-server</name>
    <description>Front End Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I am trying to run it always return me error,

```
[INFO] Total time:  0.604 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-29T23:22:55+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

I also followed the http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException. but it's not working.

I also tried the solution from https://crunchify.com/mavenmvn-clean-install-update-project-and-project-clean-options-in-eclipse-ide-to-fix-any-dependency-issue/
It's not woking again.

Moreover, I also created a new project using Spring Tool Suite 4 (Hope the different result). It's not working as well.

I normally take less than 30 mins to start a 'hello world' for new things. But for the Spring boot, It's already taken me whole day.

Please help..

Comment: How did you run the build or via command prompt?

Comment: You said "run it" but didn't specify how.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong command to run Maven. What command are you using? Try simply `mvn clean install` to compile without any options like `-P`. To run the application try `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Answer (score 0):

What command are you running? Something like "mvn clean install" should work.

Comment: Then look in target directory - java -jar yourApp.jar to run in command like.

Comment: @user1016765 Awww. It work!. What I did is following the info on the internet. right click run as...

Answer (score 0):

Go into your project folder and run this command in the terminal.

> mvn clean install -DskipTests

After that right click on your main program and click on run as spring boot app. It should work.